# How to find Machine IP of a transaction committed in SQL SERVER, we have user Name and Transaction ID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, truncate

How to find Machine IP /Host name  of the user who  committed a transaction in SQL SERVER, we have UserName ,TransactionID and TransactionTime .
Is it possible to find it using T-SQL Query ?

The operation committed is : Truncate Table

Comment: Looking for the crook that broke your system? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one might help you out. I did not write it myself, but we use this here in my org sometimes.

```
SELECT Sdest.Databasename,
       Sdes.Session_Id,
       Sdes.Host_Name,
       Sdes.Program_Name,
       Sdes.Client_Interface_Name,
       Sdes.Login_Name,
       Sdes.Login_Time,
       Sdes.Nt_Domain,
       Sdes.Nt_User_Name,
       Sdec.Client_Net_Address,
       Sdec.Local_Net_Address,
       Sdest.Objname,
       Sdest.Query
FROM Sys.Dm_Exec_Sessions AS Sdes
  INNER JOIN Sys.Dm_Exec_Connections AS Sdec ON Sdec.Session_Id = Sdes.Session_Id
  CROSS APPLY
  (
      SELECT DB_NAME(Dbid) AS Databasename,
             OBJECT_ID(Objectid) AS Objname,
             ISNULL(
             (
                 SELECT Text AS [Processing-instruction(definition)]
                 FROM Sys.Dm_Exec_Sql_Text(Sdec.Most_Recent_Sql_Handle) FOR Xml PATH(''), TYPE
                                                                                              ), '') AS Query
      FROM Sys.Dm_Exec_Sql_Text(Sdec.Most_Recent_Sql_Handle)
                                                            ) AS Sdest
WHERE Sdes.Session_Id <> @@Spid 
ORDER BY Sdec.Session_Id;
```